# How is an EJB stateful session bean passivated to secondary storage

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-passivation

I have read for stateful session bean:

> "While in the ready stage, the EJB container may decide to deactivate,
>   or passivate, the bean by moving it from memory to secondary storage"

So what is this secondary storage? Is it the underline database? Also, how is an object saved (persisted) in a relational database like Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java EE is only a specification and it is up to the [JEE compliant application server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html) (such as *Glassfish*, *Wildfly*, or *WebLogic*) to determine exactly what the *secondary storage* is.

WebLogic, at least by default, [passivates the EJB:s to disk](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24973/session.htm#EJBPG284) which is described by this image:

[image: WebLogic Stateful Session EJB Life Cycle]

The WildFly/JBoss (which is my application server of choice) documentation is quite sparse regarding this, but a fair guess is that the default behaviour is to passivate the EJB:s to disk as well, though I cannot swear on it.

So, once again, the specification doesn't give any rules on how to passivate the EJB:s, it is up to the implementation.